# Flutter styled map

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Is it possible to use json generated from [Google Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)
to stylize the Flutter native map?

Comment: Checkout this post on how to style google map on flutter :https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 28):

There is no such ability in current version. But soon it can be achieved due to [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1143/commits/2a242d18c46b1380e83dcc7bbdcc0690aec13d93) pull request

---

**Update**

Finally it has been merged with [#1697](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1697) pull request! And it's published in 0.5.16 version of google_maps_flutter.

### How to

To use this feature invoke `setMapStyle` on `GoogleMapController` instance and pass style string as a parameter.

e.g.

```
GoogleMapController mapController;
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.setMapStyle('[{"featureType": "all","stylers": [{ "color": "#C0C0C0" }]},{"featureType": "road.arterial","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{ "color": "#CCFFFF" }]},{"featureType": "landscape","elementType": "labels","stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]}]');
  }
```

From the docs:

> Sets the styling of the base map.
>
> Set to null to clear any previous custom styling.
>
> If problems were detected with the [mapStyle], including un-parsable
>   styling JSON, unrecognized feature type, unrecognized element type, or
>   invalid styler keys: [MapStyleException] is thrown and the current
>   style is left unchanged.
>
> The style string can be generated using [map style tool](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com). Also, refer
>   [iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/style-reference) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/style-reference) style reference for more information regarding the
>   supported styles.

Answer (score 4):

with the latest update of Google Map, You can do this easily.

on your onMapCreated method use `controller.setMapStyle` Use this code. You can create your own style from [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

```
void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
    controller.setMapStyle('''
    [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
    ''');
   
  }
```