# Style Google Maps in Flutter silver or black & white

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I'm using Google Maps in a Flutter app. I'm looking for a way to style the map on a black and white edition. I've seen this done in web editions, but not sure if it's possible in the Flutter edition...yet.
Wonder if anyone else has achieved this and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953913/flutter-styled-map

Comment: Also I was able to find examples and documentation in like 10 seconds by searching the web...

Comment: Well then you found something that helped me and I missed

Comment: The answer you accepted is basically a copy+paste of [this article](https://medium.com/@matthiasschuyten/google-maps-styling-in-flutter-5c4101806e83) without the details...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to get a style.json from: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and add it to your assets.

```
  assets:
    - assets/json_assets/
```

Then  you add this to your init State where the google Maps widget is

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/json_assets/map_style.txt').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
  }
```

and last but not least your Map Created function should look like this:

```
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
    _mapController = controller;
    initMemoryClustering();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the styling, but missed the setMapStyle. Thank you :)