# How to change default tiles color / map background color for Google Maps in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, maps

I'm using dark theme version of tiles but during loading, maps displays tiles/background with default bright color. How to change this color ? I'm talking about [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin. Thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953913/flutter-styled-map

Comment: @ShawnDomingo I'm already using this option for setting dark theme, but tiles are bright for a short period time until this theme is loaded..

Comment: @yousuf unfortunately no. It's still like this...